# NestJS: Set global variable on app startup

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a NestJS application.
I want to fetch `mySecret` from Azure Key Vault on app startup, something like this:

```
  const azureClient = new SecretClient(url, credential);
  const mySecret = await azureClient.getSecret("mySecret");
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

and access `mySecret` from my services.
How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

To access to your services on the app starter (main.js)

you can use `app.get()` method after the factory creates the application,

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
    ...
   const azureClientService = app.get<azureClient>(azureClient)
```